# Mediation sequence for DELETE method in wso2 not working

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

I have a SOAP web service for delete action, with endpoint URL

```
http://some-ip-address:my-port/bank/websrv/delcus
```

And can be invoked only by **POST** method. 
 
I have published this API and added **DELETE** resource for invoking this service. 
 
So the URL becomes

```
https://my-apim-endpoint/public/customer/{customer-id}
```

And I added mediation sequence for **DELETE** action. So whenever this API is invoked, it will go through the mediation sequence and send **POST** request to the endpoint

```
http://some-ip-address:my-port/bank/websrv/delcus
```

But when I invoke the API, the endpoint URL is getting replaced with the following URL.

Here is how the send mediator looks like,

```
<send>
  <endpoint>
    <http method="post" uri-template="http://some-ip-address:my-port/bank/websrv/delcus"/>
  </endpoint>
</send>
```

```
http://some-ip-address:my-port/bank/websrv/100000023
```

Instead of

```
http://some-ip-address:my-port/bank/websrv/delcus
```

And giving me error response. Please anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use http type endpoint, the resource path get appended to the endpoint url. for example say you have an endpoint http://test.com/path and if you have defined a /resource/{id} resource, then the request will be sent to http://test.com/path/resource/{id} kind of a url. That is the default behavior.

To call a SOAP service instead of using http type endpoint, you can use use address endpoint type. when you create endpoint with address type, you can define whether it is a soap11 or soap12. (format option in advanced options section in the implement tab). this will send a soap payload to http://test.com/path. (you do not have to build soap headers etc. only message body) .

Comment: I added as per you have mentioned here, so my mediation looks like this, 
`
<send>
 <endpoint>
  <address uri="http://webservice_url/delete_action" format="soap12"></address>
 </endpoint>   
</send>`

But I'm getting the following error when invoking the API.
**An error has occurred in CICS Web Support.
CICS cannot locate a resource corresponding to the URL you have specified**